# A simple method to restore the original edge order on output of networkx.minimum_cycle_basis()

Tags: python, networkx, cycle

`networkx.minimum_cycle_basis()` returns *list of nodes
which forms a cycle (loop) in G. Note that the nodes are not
necessarily returned in a order by which they appear in the cycle* as described in [minimum_cycle_basis()](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.minimum_cycle_basis.html#networkx.algorithms.cycles.minimum_cycle_basis) documentation. Here is what I did to restore their original order into `nodes` array:

```
for cycle in nx.minimum_cycle_basis(graph):
    nodes = np.array(nx.find_cycle(graph.subgraph(cycle)))[:, 0]
```

Is there a simpler, perhaps more efficient way of accomplishing it?

Comment: On the efficiency question, is the runtime of your code any significant fraction of the runtime of `nx.minimum_cycle_basis()`? The latter is an `O(n * m^2)` algorithm; your solution is `O(m)`. From the source code, minimum_cycle_basis is implemented with simplicity and following the academic paper's pseudocode in mind, not any significant optimization or performance.

Comment: @kcsquared The runtime of `nx.minimum_cycle_basis()` is acceptable for my use case. I'm mainly looking for simplification, if possible.